# I can't run my app on android studio-Run button greys out and can't build project

Tags: java, android

So i am super new to android studio and basically I'm trying to run my app but when I click run it shows this.Basically the run button greys out. Apparently I need to build my project but the build tool is not even found?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTXJx.png

I tried to sync with gradle files as suggested but I got this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wTsi.png)

Comment: seems that you have problems with android sdk location or etc

Comment: ya I got an error about sdk path so I click configure next to it and nothing changes

Comment: have you already performed a sync with gradle files? Tools > Android > Sync with gradle files

Comment: how did you imported this project? is this problem happens when you create new blank android project?

Comment: No if I create a new project it runs correctly

Comment: And they recommend migrating project to gradle how do I do that?